# Manipulacion de datos en archivo .csv en Python

Tags: python, csv

Estoy utilizando un archivo .csv  con la siguiente estructura:

```
Boleta,Nombre,Edad
123456,Pedro,20
123457,Maria,21
123458,Julia,24
123459,Raul,18
123460,Hector,22
```

y tengo que pasar todos los registros a un solo campo como se muestra a continuación:

```
 Boleta,Nombre,Edad
123456,Pedro,20,123457,Maria,21,123458,Julia,24,123459,Raul,18,123460,Hector,22
```

Si alguien me puede ayudar, estaría muy agradecido

Comment: Pon un ejemplo de cómo quieres la salida, porque no entiendo eso de "todos los registros a una sola celda"

Comment: Edito mi pregunta para ser lo mas claro posible

Comment: Un CSV es un fichero en que  los datos **ya están separados por comas** , pues CSV significa _Comma Separated Values_ (aunque hay variantes en que el separador es punto y coma). Es probable que en realidad no necesites hacer nada y ya lo tengas como querías. Habría que ver qué hay exactamente dentro del fichero .csv "como texto" (no al abrirlo en Excel).

Comment: Vuelvo a editar la pregunta haciendo las  correcciones pertientes

Comment: Es un requisito muy raro, ya que el CSV que generes de ese modo será inutilizable por tener una cabecera con 3 celdas, y luego una fila con docenas de celdas... Pero bueno, en todo caso no es un problema de csv, sino de mera manipulación de archivos. Debes leer una línea del archivo original, escribirla en el destino, y después el resto de líneas del original , reemplazando los finales de línea por comas, y volcar el resultado al fichero destino.

Comment: me parece que a este post le falta investigacion y in MRE

Comment: Hola amigo, Te recomiendo que pases a la lecturas de los siguientes artículos: 
[ask] y 
[mre] y 
[help/on-topic] y 
[help/dont-ask]

Comment: No se me ocurre que utilidad pueda tener lo que pides. ¿Es un ejercicio de clases?

Comment: @CandidMoe, si es un ejercicio de clases y el profesor no explico muy bien.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Abres un archivo de entrada y otro de salida.

```
with open("juntar.csv", "r") as datos:
    with open("salida.csv", "w") as salida:
```

Lees el primer registro de la entrada (header) y lo grabas tal cual a la salida

```
    header = datos.readline()
    salida.write(header)
    sep = ''
```

Luego lees las restantes lineas y las vas grabando a la salida. Con `strip()` eliminas el '\n' de la línea leída.

```
    for linea in datos.readlines():
        salida.write(f"{sep}{linea.strip()}")
        sep = ','
```

#### Demo

*juntar.csv*

```
boleta,Nombre,Edad
123456,Pedro,20
123457,Maria,21
123458,Julia,24
123459,Raul,18
123460,Hector,22
```

*código*

```
with open("juntar.csv", "r") as datos:
    with open("salida.csv", "w") as salida:
        header = datos.readline()
        salida.write(header)
        sep = ''
        for linea in datos.readlines():
            salida.write(f"{sep}{linea.strip()}")
            sep = ','
```

produce:

```
candid@gear:~/PycharmProjects/pandas$ more salida.csv 
boleta,Nombre,Edad
123456,Pedro,20,123457,Maria,21,123458,Julia,24,123459,Raul,18,123460,Hector,22
```

Comment: Le resolviste la tarea.. y OP no demostro nada :(

Comment: @gbianchi. Hay otras variables en juego. Circunstancias atenuantes, podriamos decir.